# GPG keys new key but contains no user ID

Tags: debian, networking, apt, gpg

I have added a new source

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib
```

to my source list file on my raspberry pi. When I update my sudo apt to confirm the changes, I get this error:

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease
Get:2 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease [46.7 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease [32.6 kB]
Err:2 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 04EE7237B7D453EC NO_PUBKEY 648ACFD622F3D138
Get:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster/main armhf Packages [330 kB]
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://httpredir.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 04EE7237B7D453EC NO_PUBKEY 648ACFD622F3D138
E: The repository 'http://httpredir.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I was given these instructions to follow:

```
gpg --recv-keys 04EE7237B7D453EC
gpg --recv-keys 648ACFD622F3D138
gpg --export 04EE7237B7D453EC | sudo apt-key add -
gpg --export 648ACFD622F3D138 | sudo apt-key add -
```

But when I carry out this command:

```
gpg --recv-keys 04EE7237B7D453EC
```

I get this error:

```
gpg: key E0B11894F66AEC98: new key but contains no user ID - skipped
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:           w/o user IDs: 1
```

Should that output occur? I followed the instructions but still got the previous errors, `public key is not available` implies their is something wrong with my keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:

The package manager needs to have the PGP keys to verify package sets from the new repository.
You first have to fetch the keys from a keyserver, e.g. the SKS one:

```
$ gpg --recv-keys --keyserver ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net 04EE7237B7D453EC
gpg: key E0B11894F66AEC98: public key "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (9/stretch) <ftpmaster@debian.org>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
$ gpg --recv-keys --keyserver ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net 648ACFD622F3D138
gpg: key DC30D7C23CBBABEE: public key "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (10/buster) <ftpmaster@debian.org>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

then import them into your local APT key store:

```
$ gpg --export 04EE7237B7D453EC | sudo apt-key add -
OK
$ gpg --export 648ACFD622F3D138 | sudo apt-key add -
OK
```

Then your apt update should work.

Comment: BTW for Debian packages, one should probably use `--keyserver keyring.debian.org`

Comment: It wasn't that you weren't using a keyserver before, it's just that the default keyserver was stripping the user IDs from the keys. This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1485255/41709) explains why.